# Linux complex file sharing between users

Tags: file-permissions, groups

Let's start with the elephant in the room: I have no formal training and I've been given a couple of small servers to manage for various, off-topic reasons. This to say that my knowledge is patchy. Please bear with me.

One of the servers is dedicated to heavy computation for a few users (less than 10) and I have been asked if I can enable fine-grain decision of file access policies between users.

What I mean with that is that my users wish to have a way to decide to grant access to their files in a per-file and per-user way. So that, for example, folderA is accessible by user1, user2 and user3, while folderB by user2 and user4 and folderC is not accessible by anyone other than the owner.

They, more or less, want a "dropbox-style" management of access management for their personal files, only for their local files, between the local users.

I was not able to find anything related, so I wonder if this is a feature that is reasonable to activate in terms of security and feasibility. I admit I never thought about it before, but it's a feature that makes sense in a multi-user server for cooperative tasks.

Since groups are not a solution (I need up to 30), Nextcloud is overkill and not for active projects you are coding on. Maybe git or PAM?

Comment: You might want to check if [ACLs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) are a option for you.

Answer (score 2):

This, or any other from the myriads of the similar products will definitely work for you.

https://owncloud.com/private-cloud/

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately ownCloud and nextCloud are mainly built for storage, which means my users cannot easily manage access/"sharing" on folders used for development and constantly updated via command line

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research on this not long ago, and a google search just now of "self-hosted dropbox style" rendered a TON of self-hosted options. From what I've read, owncloud or seafile seem to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately ownCloud and nextCloud are mainly built for storage, which means my users cannot easily manage access/"sharing" on folders used for development and constantly updated via command line